# RDF and XML iteration using Python's ElementTree with the ACM's Classification Index

Tags: xml, python-3.x, rdf, elementtree

I'm trying to iterate over a large XML document, which uses RDF namespaces, eg. *skos*. How can I iterate on a per-concept basis, i.e. where "skos:Concept" is in the RDF entry, and also traverse on an 'ID' basis, i.e. for links contained within *skos:broader* or *skos:narrower*?

My investigations so far have tried finding the RDF tag using code such as:

```
for elem in self.tree.iter():
  print(elem.text, elem.tag)
```

However this so far hasn't been enlightening.

The full XML document can be found [here](http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/2380000/2371137/ACMComputingClassificationSystemSKOSTaxonomy.xml?ip=130.88.240.67&id=2371137&acc=OPEN&key=BF07A2EE685417C5%2EA30F01C2334F920C%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E6D218144511F3437&__acm__=1532108711_8e2bd9fbd2c437f2aa0e70a803cdd65c) (warning; 20,000+ lines).

Example segment:

```
<skos:Concept rdf:about="#10011746" xml:lang="en">
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="en">Hardware reverse engineering</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:altLabel xml:lang="en">reverse engineering in hardware</skos:altLabel>
<skos:altLabel xml:lang="en">reverse engineering of hardware</skos:altLabel>
<skos:altLabel xml:lang="en">reverse engineering hardware</skos:altLabel>
<skos:inScheme rdf:resource="http://totem.semedica.com/taxonomy/The ACM Computing Classification System (CCS)"/>
<skos:broader rdf:resource="#10003001"/>
<skos:broader rdf:resource="#10003463"/>
</skos:Concept>

<skos:Concept rdf:about="#10011747" xml:lang="en">
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="en">File system security</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:altLabel xml:lang="en">file systems security</skos:altLabel>
<skos:altLabel xml:lang="en">security of file system</skos:altLabel>
<skos:altLabel xml:lang="en">security of file systems</skos:altLabel>
<skos:inScheme rdf:resource="http://totem.semedica.com/taxonomy/The ACM Computing Classification System (CCS)"/>
<skos:broader rdf:resource="#10003006"/>
</skos:Concept>
```

Comment: Try [tag:rdflib].

Comment: I already have with no luck, is there a specific function you'd recommend for parsing it?

Comment: https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro_to_graphs.html#basic-triple-matching ?